# Setting UTF-8 in php

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I am trying to make a simple table of clients which will be in russian language.
But problem is, it gives me some unknown letters in mysql.

For example my problem is like this:

1. I put data in russian to my form
2. form inserts data into datatable in russian
3. database shows unknown letters
4. table in webapp shows in russian properly and can be edited in russian aswell.

only results from within mysql give unknown letters

**Here are my settings for enabling utf8**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Also have set my mysql database as:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

```
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

I looked for many information about this issue and thought it was php file encoding problem. So I've also added

```
header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

I also tried by adding

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

but now it doesnt load whole table..

Please help me with your tips

Thank you in advance

Comment: why make snippets of unrunnable text? why the tag spam of javascript and jqueery?

Comment: `mysqli_set_charset('utf8');` needs the first parameter to be the connection, e.g. `mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');`

Comment: "but now it doesnt load whole table", "some unknown letters" -- what do you mean??  Please show examples of code and letters.

Comment: Do you have `<form ... accept-charset="UTF-8">`